# How to use custom delimiter while creating table in Hive using create-hive-table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import data to HDFS from a RDBMS table. I am then using create-hive-table to copy schema to hive and then load data to that hive table.

command used to import to HDFS

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop --username sqoop --password sqoop --table customers --warehouse-dir testingsqoop -m 1 --fields-terminated-by ',' --enclosed-by "\'" --lines-terminated-by "\n"
```

command used to create hive table:

```
sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop --username sqoop --password sqoop --table customers --hive-table customers --fields-terminated-by "," --enclosed-by "\'" --lines-terminated-by "\n"
```

And finally the query used to load data to hive

```
load data inpath '/user/cloudera/testingsqoop/customers/*' into table customers;
```

As I am enclosing the fields with a single quote `'`, hive while creating the table is not considering the `--enclosed-by` flag, hence the columns in the hive table are still having quotes `'`.

```
NULL  'Richard'  'Hernandez'  'XXXXXXXXX'  'XXXXXXXXX'  '6303 Heather Plaza'  'Brownsville'  'TX'  '78521'
```

However if I don't use `--enclosed-by` it works fine, but i want to have it.

1) Could you please help regarding this?

2) Also is there any way i can specify multiple chars for field terminator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

--fields-terminated-by \01
--hive-drop-import-delims 
--null-string \N
--null-non-string \N

in your sqoop import data query and hive table definition queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most likely, your syntax is causing the exception. Try using:

   --enclosed-by "'"

instead of \'.

2. Yes, you can import with multiple characters set as the field delimiters.